# Excel Auto Fill Value for every month

Tags: excel, spreadsheet, autofill

I'm creating a spreadsheet in excel to track my estimated daily cash flow.  I have auto filled every date for the next year in one column.  In the next column I would like to auto fill values for my bills on the day they are due.  For example, my mortgage is due on the 1st, so for every 1st, for every month I'd like to autofill the cost of my mortgage.

Thanks anyone for some help on this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your dates are in column A, and your mortgage bill is in column B you could use the following formula in cell B2 and drag down for each date:

```
=IF(day(A2)=1,"1500","")
```

**Note:**

Also assuming in the above formula that your mortgage amount would be 1500. The above formula checks which day of the month the date is, and displays the 1500 of it's the 1st, or stays blank if it isn't the 1st.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I am following, but you want to Fill by copying a month at a time?

Take a look at [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/291359) on how to use the AutoFill Options and select Copy Cells (instead of Fill Series) to copy the cells repeatedly.